# Python py-cord / discord.py(2.0.0): Button interaction failed

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

If I click on my Button everything works as expected, but in Discord is's showing:

[image]

This is the Button Code:

```
# Start Button
start_b = Button(label="Starten", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)

async def start_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if not is_server_running():
        msg = await interaction.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='START: Starte Server'))
        start_server()
        await msg.delete()
    else:
        msg = await interaction.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Server läuft noch'))
        time.sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()

start_b.callback = start_callback

...

view.add_item(start_b)
await bot.get_channel(Some ID).send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Dashboard"), view=view)
```

I guess I have to acknowledge the button interaction somehow.
Is there a way to do this without sending reply messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it

You have to add this at the top of your callback:

```
await interaction.response.defer()
```

In my example this would be:

```
# Start Button
start_b = Button(label="Starten", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)

async def start_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):

await interaction.response.defer() # <---- Here

    if not is_server_running():
        msg = await interaction.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='START: Starte Server'))
        start_server()
        await msg.delete()
    else:
        msg = await interaction.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Server läuft noch'))
        time.sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()

start_b.callback = start_callback

...

view.add_item(start_b)
await bot.get_channel(Some ID).send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Dashboard"), view=view)
```

Comment: An interaction in discord demands you to respond to it within 3 seconds. Generally, deferring is done if the processes before response takes more than 3 seconds. You must use [`interaction.response.send_message`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=interactionresponse%20edit_message#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message) or [`interaction.response.edit_message`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=interactionresponse%20edit_message#discord.InteractionResponse.edit_message) preferably.